# Connect to SFTP server using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, sftp, putty

I am able to connect to SFTP server using WinSCP successfully. However, when trying with Jmeter using SSH SFTP with the below information, getting "Algorithm negotiation fail".

1. Hostname
2. Port: 22
3. username
4. Private key/SSH Key File in openSSH format (with extension as .key/.pem)
5. Action: get
6. Path: target path
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case your SSH server is using an algorithm which is not supported by Java

To be 100% sure you need to try connecting to your SSH server using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [increase JSCH logging verbosity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826894/jsch-logger-where-can-i-configure-the-level) in [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).

Most probably you will need to download and install [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html) and then your connection should be successful.